# Monitor Displaying "No Signal" with RetroPie at Powerup

Tags: pi-3, hdmi, power-supply, retropie

I'm in the process of building a game console using RetroPie and a Raspberry Pi 3. I'm connecting the Pi to a monitor via HDMI, and I'm powering both using a power strip with an on/off switch, to allow the entire console to be turned on or off with the single switch. However, when I turn the power switch on, both the monitor and Pi power on correctly, but the monitor displays "No Signal".

When I disconnect and reconnect the Pi (while the monitor is still powered on), the Pi boots up and the monitor displays it just fine. The problem only occurs when both devices are plugged into the power strip and the strip is switched on.

Does anyone know what could be causing this and how to fix it? The goal is to be able to turn on both devices with a single switch.

Comment: there are a lot of settings you may wish to try.  what is your current configuration?  hdmi_safe? hdmi_force_hotplug?

Answer (score 0):

I have this exact problem, but for my TV, an RCA 22 inch, I have to wait until it goes to the no signal screen, then power the pi. If you want to turn them both on with one switch, add a timer.